# Is there a node-based implementation for saturation that works a little more like Photoshop?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, color, mathematics

I am asking this question because I am putting together a node group to adjust some basic color and contrast settings for texture maps. I really hate the way that Blender's Hue/Saturation node saturates and de-saturates things. It just looks ugly and gets really extreme (I also hate the bright/contrast node, but I'll save that for another post).

I came across [this video](https://www.blendernation.com/2018/02/11/whats-wrong-blender-saturation/) that goes into detail about the issue. But his fix (Convert To BW Node > Mix Shader) only de-saturates. It won't saturate at all.

Can someone point me in the right direction with respect to creating a better saturation solution?

Sorry if some of my terminology is awkward, I'm not much of a color scientist. Any help at all would be hugely appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

---

I found some hue/saturation algorithms here on StackExchange, but I don't know exactly how to implement them as I am pretty horrible at mathematics.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806483/increase-or-decrease-color-saturation

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404507/algorithm-for-hue-saturation-adjustment-layer-from-photoshop

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364716/faster-algorithm-to-change-hue-saturation-lightness-in-a-bitmap

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966121/what-is-the-algorithm-for-vibrance-filters

Really hoping that someone here could help me implement a better saturation algorithm using nodes (shader editor, not compositor) in Blender.